# ID dinâmico com Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Eu tenho uma função que ele cria um span com id, porém preciso que esse id seja gerado dinâmicamente exemplo id="span1" / id="span2", como eu faço isso?

```
$("#lista").append("<span id='span'><br> " + label + " - R$" + valor + "</span>" );
```

Comment: Já tentou criar uma variável com o valor, concatená-la junto ao `id` e incrementá-la a cada elemento adicionado?

Comment: Não seria melhor utilizar uma classe ? Na maior parte dos casos resolve o problema sem necessitar de fazer esse genero de coisas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conte quantos `span`s que contenham o `id` que começa com "span" e some com `+1`. Isso irá criar um novo `id` sequencial:

```js
var label = "label";
var valor = "10,00";

function addSpan(){
   var span_id = $("#lista span[id^='span']").length+1; // novo id
   $("#lista").append("<span id='span" + span_id + "'><br> " + label + " - R$" + valor + " - id: span"+ span_id +"</span>" );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="lista"></div>
<button onclick="addSpan()">Adicionar span</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

A maneira mais fácil que vejo é:

```
var x = 0;
$('O QUE VOCE ESCOLHER').click(function(){
    x++;
$("#lista").append(`<span id='span${x}'><br>  ${label} - R$ ${valor} "</span>` );
});
```

Ao invés de usar aspas simples ' ou aspas duplas "" coloque a crase, e pra cada variável você bota dentro de `${}` daí o js já entende que o que está dentro de `${}` é uma variável.